# Custom button for facebook login using Kotlin but failed

Tags: android, facebook, firebase, kotlin

I would like to apply facebook login module by clicking the custom button and acquire access token from facebook, then pass the access token from Facebook to firebase to Login.

When it comes the execution, there has no response from register call back.

I have setup the Facebook Developer App called : JacksonApplication and  the application written in Kotlin as below:

Would you please tell me what are other ways I have to implement ?

```
class JacksonApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        JodaTimeAndroid.init(this);
    }
}
```

My function :

```
 callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

            LoginManager.getInstance()
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager ,
                    object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                        override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                            println("facebook loginResult : $loginResult")
                            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.accessToken);
                            // App code
                        }

                        override fun onCancel() {
                            // App code
                        }

                        override fun onError(exception: FacebookException) {
                            println("loginResult : ${exception.localizedMessage}")

                            // App code
                        }
                    })

 fun  handleFacebookAccessToken( token : AccessToken) {
        Log.d(TAG, "handleFacebookAccessToken:" + token);

        val credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(token.getToken());
        mAuth!!.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this) { task ->
                    if (task.isSuccessful) {
                        // Sign in success
                        val firebaseUser = mAuth!!.currentUser
                        updateUI(firebaseUser)

                    } else {
                        // Sign in fails
                        val currentUser = mAuth!!.currentUser!!
                        user.register(currentUser.uid)
                    }
                }
    }
```

My actions :

```
private fun loginSocial( type : String ) {
        if (type  == "Facebook") {
            println("execute social reg by facebook")
            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create()

            LoginManager.getInstance()
            LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager ,
                    object : FacebookCallback<LoginResult> {
                        override fun onSuccess(loginResult: LoginResult) {
                            println("facebook loginResult : $loginResult")
                            handleFacebookAccessToken(loginResult.accessToken);
                            // App code
                        }

                        override fun onCancel() {
                            // App code
                        }

                        override fun onError(exception: FacebookException) {
                            println("loginResult : ${exception.localizedMessage}")

                            // App code
                        }
                    })

        }else if(type  == "Google") {
            println("execute social reg by google")

            val intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN)
            mGoogleApiClient!!.connect()
        }
    }
```

onActivity Result :

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int , resultCode: Int , data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode , resultCode , data)
    callbackManager?.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_SIGN_IN) {

         progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this )
         progressDialog!!.setMessage(this.resources.getString(R.string.loading))
         progressDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
         progressDialog!!.show()

        val result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data)
        if (result.isSuccess) {
            // successful -> authenticate with Firebase
            val account = result.signInAccount
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account!!)
        } else {
            // failed -> update UI
            updateUI(null)
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "SignIn: failed!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }else  {
         progressDialog = ProgressDialog(this )
         progressDialog!!.setMessage(this.resources.getString(R.string.loading))
         progressDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
         progressDialog!!.show()


     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these lines in onActivityResult()

```
 public override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == YOUR_GOOGLE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
        try {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account!!)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e)
            // ...
        }
    } else {
        // Pass the activity result back to the Facebook SDK
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried onActivityResult to handle google sign in together.should  this line of code be put just below         super.onActivityResult(requestCode , resultCode , data)
?

Comment: Or is it better to use default social Login button  for better UX/UI ?

Comment: Users are familiar with default social Login buttons. However, if you want to add your touch in design it will be better depending on your page design.

Comment: Still don't get it

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I forgot to add my OAuth redirect URI (found in Firebase console) to my Facebook app configuration. Thought I'd just say that just in case.